# Using GEKKO for switch mode power electronics circuit

Tags: gekko

I recently came across GEKKO and APMonitor when I looked into python toolkits for solving systems of differential algebraic equations that arise from modelling switch mode power supply circuits like a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter), for example.

The circuit model is straightforward to derive by hand using a modified node analysis or tableau approach. The model is non-linear and time-varying. The concept of steady state applies after "averaging out" the high frequency switching (this is different from just setting derivatives to 0 in the full model).

The expression for one of the equations looks like

[image: equations]

With LaTeX:

```
$d=e_1-e_3\\
0=i_1 + G_{on}(d)\left (1+\frac{V_{DR}(t)-|V_{DR}(t)|}{2V_{DR}(t)}\right)+\frac{g_1+g_2}{2}(d)+\frac{g_1-g_2}{2}|d|$
```

My goal is to use a technique such as Parameter Estimation to solve for circuit element values, if I can supply a desired circuit response (node voltages and/or branch voltages and currents) and minimize the difference from the actual response.
I should also be able to simulate my model if I already know the element values. The latter point I am stuck on because I do not see provision in the documentation for specifying a periodic time-varying input. To be specific, I need to include a square wave voltage source commanding the gate-source FET voltage (the V_DR(t) in the above equation).
**Am I sufficiently outside the intended use case of GEKKO?**

Answer (score 0):

Gekko should work well for this type of application. Here is a simple inductor / capacitor model with a simulated square wave voltage input. Define the input with

```py
# Duty Cycle
D = m.MV(value=0.5, lb=0.0, ub=1.0, integer=True) # Duty cycle (0 to 1)
# initial guess / simulation
Dv = np.ones_like(m.time); Dv[30:]=0; Dv[50:]=1; Dv[70:]=0; Dv[90:]=1
D.value = Dv
```

or another input defined as a Numpy array or Python list.

[image: Simulated Duty Cycle]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the circuit parameters
Vin = 12.0    # Input voltage (V)
Rload = 4.0   # Load resistance (ohms)
Vout_ref = 5.0 # Reference output voltage (V)

# Create a GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = np.linspace(0,1e-6,101)

# Duty Cycle
D = m.MV(value=0.5, lb=0.0, ub=1.0, integer=True) # Duty cycle (0 to 1)
# initial guess / simulation
Dv = np.ones_like(m.time); Dv[30:]=0; Dv[50:]=1; Dv[70:]=0; Dv[90:]=1
D.value = Dv
D.STATUS = 0

# Constants
L = m.FV(5e-3,lb=4.5e-3,ub=5.5e-3) # Inductor value (H)
C = m.FV(100e-6,lb=90e-6,ub=110e-6) # Capacitor value (F)
L.STATUS = 0
C.STATUS = 0

# Equations (circuit model)
Vout = m.Var()  # Inductor voltage
Iout = m.Var()  # Inductor current
m.Equation(Vout.dt() == (Vin * D - Vout) / (L * C) - Iout / C)
m.Equation(Iout.dt() == (Vin * D - Vout) / L)

# Objective (minimize output voltage error)
m.Minimize((Vout - Vout_ref)**2)

# Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # Control optimization mode (Dynamic Optimization)
m.options.NODES = 3  # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # IPOPT solver (use APOPT solver for D={0,1} with integer solution)

# Solve the optimization problem
m.solve()

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time, Vout.value, label='Output Voltage')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[Vout_ref,Vout_ref],'r--',label='Target Voltage')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time, Iout.value, label='Output Current')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time, D.value, label='Duty cycle')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('circuit.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Set the `STATUS=1` to optimize the input duty cycle, inductor size, and capacitor size. This produces a continuous duty cycle value between 0 and 1. The steady state duty cycle converges to about 0.41.

```py
D.STATUS = 1
L.STATUS = 1
C.STATUS = 1
```

[image: Optimized input]

If you need `D` to be a binary variable with values strictly `{0,1}` then switch to the APOPT solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. Mixed Integer solutions can take much longer with `2^100` possible solutions because there are 100 decision points in the horizon.

If there are discrete non-integer choices for the inductor and capacitor then use the Special Ordered Set type in Gekko with something like `L = m.sos1([4e-3,5e-3,8e-3,1e-2])`. This will choose one of the discrete values, but also introduces additional binary variables.

Use `m.abs3()` for the absolute value instead of `np.abs()` or `m.abs()` because they are not continuously differentiable. This also introduces a binary variable so `m.abs2()` may be necessary to find a solution. There are also methods to approximate absolute value or reformulate the equations to get a positive values such as `m.sqrt(v**2)`.

Here is a complete script with the different solution options:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the circuit parameters
Vin = 12.0    # Input voltage (V)
Rload = 4.0   # Load resistance (ohms)
Vout_ref = 5.0 # Reference output voltage (V)

# Create a GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
m.time = np.linspace(0,1e-6,101)

# Duty Cycle
D = m.MV(value=0.5, lb=0.0, ub=1.0, integer=True) # Duty cycle (0 to 1)
# initial guess / simulation
Dv = np.ones_like(m.time); Dv[30:]=0; Dv[50:]=1; Dv[70:]=0; Dv[90:]=1
D.value = Dv
D.STATUS = 0

# Constants
L = m.FV(5e-3,lb=4.5e-3,ub=5.5e-3) # Inductor value (H)
C = m.FV(100e-6,lb=90e-6,ub=110e-6) # Capacitor value (F)
L.STATUS = 0
C.STATUS = 0

# Equations (circuit model)
Vout = m.Var()  # Inductor voltage
Iout = m.Var()  # Inductor current
m.Equation(Vout.dt() == (Vin * D - Vout) / (L * C) - Iout / C)
m.Equation(Iout.dt() == (Vin * D - Vout) / L)

# Objective (minimize output voltage error)
m.Minimize((Vout - Vout_ref)**2)

# Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # Control optimization mode (Dynamic Optimization)
m.options.NODES = 3  # Collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # IPOPT solver (use APOPT solver for D={0,1} with integer solution)

# Initialize the simulation problem
m.solve()

# Optimize circuit with continuous D (0-1)
D.STATUS=1
L.STATUS=1
C.STATUS=1
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve()

# Optimize circuit with discrete D {0,1}
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve()

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time, Vout.value, label='Output Voltage')
plt.plot([0,m.time[-1]],[Vout_ref,Vout_ref],'r--',label='Target Voltage')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time, Iout.value, label='Output Current')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time, D.value, label='Duty cycle')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.savefig('circuit.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

The mixed integer solution (last one) is slow, but the others complete in less than 1 sec.